# How do I increase text size in metpy using declarative syntax?

Tags: metpy

Is there a way to access the native matplotlib objects that the declarative syntax makes use of internally?

Answer (score 0):

For MetPy's declarative interface, all of the plot objects e.g. `PlotObs`, `ContourPlot` have a `.handle` attribute that point to the created matplotlib object (though this is only available after the plot is drawn generally). Also, the `MapPanel` you create has a `.ax` attribute you can use to get to the appropriate `Axes` object from matplotlib. This *should* always be available and create the `Axes` as necessary.

Regarding fontsize, I assume this is either for sizing of `PlotObs` or for contour labels for `ContourPlot`. Unfortunately, neither of these expose the font size, but that would, in my opinion, be a reasonable [feature request](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%3A+Feature&template=feature_request.md).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get at resizing text until a feature for changing the text `size` can be added is to create a bigger image through the size attribute on the `PanelContainer()`. It's not a perfect solution, but it will work relatively well for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't allow as much control as might be desirable, but

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})

increased the font size for all text in the image, which was still helpful.